# Enable MTP using ADB

Tags: android, adb, mtp

How do I enable MTP mode on an Android phone, solely using ADB on the command line?
The screen cannot be used and I need to access files.
I have USB debugging enabled, though.

```
adb shell svc usb setFunction mtp
```

does not work.

Comment: Does your Android device have a custom recovery such as TWRP?

Answer (score 14):

you lacked the "s" in "setFunctions".

```
 "adb shell svc usb setFunctions mtp" worked for me in Android 9 (lineage OS).
```

Comment: In my case I had to use "setFunction". Android 7.1.2 (LineageOS for microG 14.1)

Answer (score 6):

On my galaxy S8 (android 9.0 i think), i used:

```
adb shell svc usb setFunction mtp true
```

once my phone had been connected to the computer and USB debugging enabled

I think the final parameter "true" on the end is optional but is false by default. I'm not exactly sure what difference it makes all I know is that without the "true" it didn't work.

Comment: This worked after I connected with TCPIP and accept the authorization dialogue on my phone.
```
adb connect 192.168.1.53:5555
```

Comment: I had the same issue on the athene running lineageOS 15.1 unofficial.